# Customise sparkline tooltip in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, sparklines

I have a data set like the one shown in the link. Basically, there are 2 columns, one is Date and another Value.

[image: dataset]

How can I create a sparkline in Shiny with tooltip showing both date and value? 
I found an example given in this link:

```
  output$sparkBox <- renderValueBox({
tags$div(class = "col-sm-4",
         tags$div(class = "small-box bg-aqua",
                  tags$div(class = "inner",
                           h3(data[3]),
                           p("Best Price")),
                  tags$div(class = "spark",
                           sparkline:::sparklineOutput("sprk", 150, 80),
                           sparkline:::sparkline(outputid = "sprk", 
                                                 values = data,
                                                 tooltipFormat =  '${{y}}',
                                                 width = 150, height = 80)
                  )))
```

})

When I plot value as the sparkline, how can I add date value into the tooltipFormat field? e.g. "2016-10: 1234"

Appreciate for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but I just found out about `sparkline`

```
sparkline(outputid = "sprk", 
          values = data,
          tooltipFormat =  '{{x}}: ${{y}}',
          width = 150, height = 80)
```

should do the trick